# Setup a Firedac fdquery and fdconnection in runtime

Tags: delphi, firedac

I need to setup/run a fdconnection and fdquery, in runtime. But how?

I am trying this in my code:

```
var
 LocalConnection: TFDConnection;
 LicencasTable: TFDQuery;
 FDPhysMySQLDriverLink1: TFDPhysMySQLDriverLink;
 FDGUIxWaitCursor1: TFDGUIxWaitCursor;
 oParams: TStrings;
begin

  LocalConnection := TFDConnection.Create(Self);

  FDPhysMySQLDriverLink1 := TFDPhysMySQLDriverLink.Create(Self);
  FDGUIxWaitCursor1      := TFDGUIxWaitCursor.Create(Self);
  FDPhysMySQLDriverLink1.VendorLib := ExtractFilePath(Application.exename)+'libmysql.dll';


  try
   if Variaveis.hostbd <> '' then begin
    oParams := TStringList.Create;
    oParams.Add('Server=' + Variaveis.hostbd);
    oParams.Add('Database='+Variaveis.databasebd);
    oParams.Add('User_Name='+Variaveis.usuariobd);
    oParams.Add('Password='+Variaveis.password);
    oParams.Add('DriverID=MySQL');
    LocalConnection.Params.UserName := Variaveis.usuariobd;
    LocalConnection.Params.Password := Variaveis.password;
    FDManager.AddConnectionDef('bloqueio', 'MySQL', oParams);
    LocalConnection.DriverName := 'MySQL';
    LocalConnection.LoginPrompt := false;
    LocalConnection.Connected := true;
    if LocalConnection.Connected then
        // Busca o registro do sistema no bd
        LicencasTable := TFDQuery.Create(Self);
        LicencasTable.Connection :=  LocalConnection;
        ShowMessage(Pchar(LicencasTable.Connection));
        LicencasTable.Close;
        LicencasTable.SQL.Clear;
        ShowMessage('Before open');
        LicencasTable.Open('select * from licencas');
        ShowMessage('After open');
        LicencasTable.Active := true;
        if LicencasTable.Active  then begin
          ShowMessage('Active');
        end;
        if not LicencasTable.Active  then begin
          ShowMessage('This is not Active');
        end;
   end;
  except
    oParams.Free;
  end;
```

Everything works correctly, until reach the "**LicencasTable.Open('select * from licencas');**"

The query.open simply dont works, and gives me no error too. Why not open, and not show me a error?

What am I forgetting to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code:

```
procedure ConnectLiveTest( fdc: String );    
  var i: Integer;    
begin    
dm.fdc.Connected:= False;     
  for i :=  0 to dm.ComponentCount -1 do    
      if dm.Components[ i ] is TFDQuery then        
        begin     
        if fdc = 'Live' then        
            begin      
              with dm.fdc.Params as TFDPhysMSSQLConnectionDefParams do    
                begin    
                  Server  := 'server ip address';    
                  Database:= 'dbname';    
                  UserName:= 'username';    
                  Password:= 'password';    
                end;    
            end    
            else    
            begin    
                with dm.fdc.Params as TFDPhysMSSQLConnectionDefParams do    
                  begin    
                    Server  := 'alt ip address';    
                    Database:= 'Testdbname';    
                    UserName:= 'username';    
                    Password:= 'password';    
                  end;    
            end;    
        
          dm.fdc.Connected:= True;    
          TFDQuery( dm.Components[ i ]).Active:= True;    
        end;    
    end;
```

So I just use one Firedac connection ('fdc') and when I activate the main form I pass either 'Live' or 'Test' to the above procedure which connects to the desired Server.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is incorrect in a couple of ways. First, you don't have to close it or clear the SQL on a newly created query. Second, you don't typically use the `Open` method to set up the SQL statement. Third, you're using a `try..except` to free resources, which is incorrect; if no exception occurs, you have a memory leak. You should be using a `try..finally` instead.

```
 try
   if Variaveis.hostbd <> '' then begin
    oParams := TStringList.Create;
    oParams.Add('Server=' + Variaveis.hostbd);
    oParams.Add('Database='+Variaveis.databasebd);
    oParams.Add('User_Name='+Variaveis.usuariobd);
    oParams.Add('Password='+Variaveis.password);
    oParams.Add('DriverID=MySQL');
    LocalConnection.Params.UserName := Variaveis.usuariobd;
    LocalConnection.Params.Password := Variaveis.password;
    FDManager.AddConnectionDef('bloqueio', 'MySQL', oParams);
    LocalConnection.DriverName := 'MySQL';
    LocalConnection.LoginPrompt := false;
    LocalConnection.Connected := true;
    if LocalConnection.Connected then
    begin
        // Busca o registro do sistema no bd
        LicencasTable := TFDQuery.Create(Self);
        LicencasTable.Connection :=  LocalConnection;
        ShowMessage(Pchar(LicencasTable.Connection));
        ShowMessage('Before open');
        LicencasTable.SQL.Text := 'select * from licencas';
        LicencasTable.Active := true;
        if LicencasTable.Active  then begin
          ShowMessage('Active');
        end;
        if not LicencasTable.Active  then begin
          ShowMessage('This is not Active');
        end;
    end;
  finally
    oParams.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: Based on your code i give this: -340. Driver id is not defined. Set TFDConnection.DriverName... But DriverID and DriverName is seted correctly

Comment: My suggestion would be for you to start a new FMX application, drop a TFDConnection on the form, set it up the way you want it, test it to make sure it works by making the connection active. Then view the contents of the .FMX file to see how it's configured there. Then you have the proper information to use in your code. I can't do that for you, because I don't have MySQL installed or your database to connect with.

Comment: Thx Ken , i will try. The code I'm trying to do is in a component, not visual. Whenever the application in which this component is inserted is started, it simply has to set the connection to dbmysql via firedac and make an insert inside a table,  all at runtime. Any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, do exactly what I suggested. You'll have the correct information needed to configure the connection, which you can then use to figure out what needs to be set up in your code. Drop the TFDConnection on a new, empty application's main form, set it up to properly connect to your database, and then read the .fmx file to see how the connection parameters are set up. You could also just require the user of your component to set up their own connection and then assign that connection to your component, in the same way that a TDataSource requires you to set up a dataset and assign it.